# Enum VS Static Class (Normal and With String Values)

Tags: c#, java, android, windows-phone-7

I have been developing for windows mobile and android for sometime. And I'm confused about these two concepts.

Let's say I want to make decision based on some the user's device Screen Size. So I'll expect so predefined values. I could use a switch statement for handling my logic.
But I'm not sure whether I should use Enum of a Static Class for this purpose. Which one is a better approach. 
I can do my logic in these two different ways. Which one is the correct approach? I'm confused. **And is it possible for me to use String values also?** Because currently I'm sticking with classes, I need to update to use all enums. So How about changing my Class to String Enum? Any way. Thanks.

**Using Enum**

```
//My predefined values
public enum ScreenSizeEnum
{
    Small, Medium, Large, XLarge,
}
//Handling Logic
private void SetScreenSize(ScreenSizeEnum Screen)
{
    switch (Screen)
    {
        case ScreenSizeEnum.Large:
            //Do Logic
            break;
        case ScreenSizeEnum.Small:
            //Do Logic
            break;
    }
}
```

**Using Class**

```
//My predefined values
public class ScreenSizeClass
{
    public const int Small = 0;
    public const int Medium = 1;
    public const int Large = 2;
    public const int XLarge = 3;
}
//Handling Logic
private void SetScreenSize(int Screen)
{
    switch (Screen)
    {
        case ScreenSizeClass.Large:
            //Do Logic
            break;
        case ScreenSizeClass.Small:
            //Do Logic
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The debugging experience with enums is much better (at least in c#). Try debugging a switch with a hundred cases that switches on an `int` code.

Comment: There's a 'Java' tag on this question. The example code you show for your `enum` will not work with Java. Enums in Java don't work the same way as with C# when using `switch`.

Comment: Yeah. I know that. I'm doing exactly the same flow in my android application also. I thought it might be too long if I put java code also. But I hope the concept is the same.

Comment: Akhil Sekharan, check my last edit concerning strings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Enumeration Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> An enumeration type (also named an enumeration or an enum) provides an
> efficient way to define a set of named integral constants that may be
> assigned to a variable.
>
> The following are advantages of using an enum instead of a numeric
> type:
>
> 1. You clearly specify for client code which values are valid for the variable.
> 2. In Visual Studio, IntelliSense lists the defined values.

So if you pass `enum`, it is strongly typed, so you automatically get control over what you can pass into a method.

```
ScreenSizeEnum screenSize = ScreenSizeEnum.Medium;
SetScreenSize(screenSize);
```

When using `const` or `static` fields you definitely need to check whether the passed `int` value is taken from the expected diapason.

```
int someScreenSizeValue = ...; //anything
SetScreenSize(someScreenSizeValue); //compiles

private void SetScreenSize(int screenSizeValue)
{
    switch (screenSizeValue)
    {
        case ScreenSizeClass.Large:
            //Do Logic
            break;
        case ScreenSizeClass.Small:
            //Do Logic
            break;
        default: 
            // something else, what to do??
            break;
    }
}
```

---

*Based on comments:*

If it's necessary to check, whether some `int` is defined in `enum`, one can do something like this:

```
int somevallue = 0;
if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ScreenSizeEnum), somevallue))
{
    //it's ok
}
```

Or an extension method:

```
public static T GetEnumValue<T>(this string value) where T : struct
{
    Type t = typeof(T);

    if (!t.IsEnum)
    {
        throw new Exception("T must be an enum");
    }
    else
    {
        T result;

        if (Enum.TryParse<T>(value, out result))
            return result;
        
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

which could be used

```
int someValue = 1;
ScreenSizeEnum screenSize = someValue.GetEnumValue<ScreenSizeEnum>();
```

---

As for the `string` (based on OP's edited question):

From [enum (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> The approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int,
> uint, long, or ulong.

So you cannot have an enum of strings. But you can use names from enums, as `ToString` method returns the name, not the value of the enum.

```
ScreenSizeEnum.Small.ToString(); //Small
```

So you can have another extension method on strings:

```
public static T GetEnumValue<T>(this string value) where T : struct
{
    Type t = typeof(T);

    if (!t.IsEnum)
    {
        throw new Exception("T must be an enum");
    }
    else
    {
        if (Enum.IsDefined(t, value))
            return (T)Enum.Parse(t, value);
        
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

So that

```
int intScreenSize = (int)ScreenSizeEnum.Small;
string strScreenSize = ScreenSizeEnum.Small.ToString();
ScreenSizeEnum intScreenSizeValue = intScreenSize.GetEnumValue<ScreenSizeEnum>(); //ScreenSizeEnum.Small
ScreenSizeEnum strScreenSizeValue = strScreenSize.GetEnumValue<ScreenSizeEnum>(); //ScreenSizeEnum.Small
```

Comment: You can always cast an arbitrary `int` to an enum so you should still check enums for validity too.

Comment: @mikez That is another question and besides there is nice bunch of methods for that.

Answer (score 9):

This is precisely what enums are there for. Not that you can't use the static class with the constants, but enum is by far cleaner...

Comment: That's right. The users of SetScreenSize() clearly known they have to pass specific values and not an int who may be the screen width like 640.

Comment: Except don't attempt to use `enums` in Java the way the OP has demonstrated in their question.

Answer (score 1):

enums are basically used when you want a variable or parameter to have value from a fixed set of possible constants. You can replace enums with class with a set of static final int constants. But using enums is more flexible & readable appraoch over the later one.

Answer (score 0):

A class can be very handy if you want more as the enumerator only. If you want to implement several Get... functions that can return other things that you need.

My example is that I have a class of some type but there is a related other type that I need to.