# Object oriented c#

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class called Promotion (model class). I want a promotion to have a type called Category where Category is its own model class I'm assuming where I would define all the types of categories such as fast food foot wear jewelry and so on. I'm not quite sure of how to go about this though so for example, my class called category is already a set thing but my class promotion is something where before I create it I need to set it with a category  with the viable category options. thank you!

Comment: Is the **Category** class reads values from somewhere OR is it Enum OR contains constant values? And why don't you create a property called `Categories` of type `Category` in the `Promotion`?

Comment: That's a great idea @Patrik Gaikwad. that's exactly what I want to do. What is the different / benefitsfor doing enum vs constant values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you create a property called `Categories` of type `Category` in the `Promotion`?

```
enum Algorithms
{
    FCFS,
    SJF,
    PRIORITY,
    RR
}

class Process
{
   public Algorithm algorithms{get;}
}
```

For the detailed difference please read the answer from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696098/enum-vs-static-class-normal-and-with-string-values)

Comment: That's a great idea @Patrik Gaikwad. that's exactly what I want to do. What is the difference / benefitsfor doing enum vs constant values?

Comment: I mean it didn't I'm asking how to actually code it then I would accept it

Comment: added a sample from the code that I'm working on. Please modify according to your needs.